# Saving Sitefinity Forms Module Data to separate Database

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-feather

I'm working with Sitefinity CMS and trying to figure out how to save the data from a "Forms Module" form to a separate database in the backend.  Currently all the responses are saved into a table that is created when the form is built.  What I want to do is re-route the save request to go through my code behind instead and save the data to Azure table storage.  Is there a way to do this or by using the Forms Module am I stuck to saving the data to the table that is auto-created when the form is built? I've tried creating my own FormsSubmitRouteHandler as explained here (http://docs.sitefinity.com/for-developers-submit-forms-using-ajax-call#register-a-form-submit-route-handler) but I must be doing something wrong cause my code doesn't ever get hit.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  If I didn't explain myself well please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new provider that implements the FormsDataProvider class.
Currently Sitefinity uses OpenAccessFormsProvider - so you can use JustDecompile to see how that was implemented and probably do something similar. 
Then you need to register your custom provider in the Administration > Settings > Advanced > Forms

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind having the form responses in the Sitefinity database and in your custom storage, then you can subscribe to the IFormEntryCreatedEvent and in your event handler you can write the logic of saving the form respose somewhere else.
See this article for more details: http://docs.sitefinity.com/for-developers-forms-events#iformentrycreatedevent

Have in mind that this will result in form responses being saved in both, the SF datbase and your custom storage. Also, you won't be able to manage the entries stored in the custyom storage through Sitefinity backend. If that's your goal, then Vesselin's answer is the correct way to go, but more complicated.

Comment: After messing around with it last week I actually ended up doing it this way.